# How to access event object in a method with debounce - Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

Can't get `event` object in a debounced method:

```
methods: {
  fetchData: _.debounce(function(e) {
    console.log(e) // return undefined
  }, 500)
}
```

Is it possible to access event object in a method? My purpose is to check, what keycodes what pressed:

```
if (e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 80) {
  // do some stuff
}
```

I call method `fetchData` this way:

```
<input @keyup="fetchData()" v-model="name" type="text">
```

Comment: how do you call methods.fetchData?

Comment: @Justcode, updated an answer.

Comment: You mean something like this https://jsbin.com/lufahez/edit?html,js,console,output?

Comment: Yes, i expected it to work this way, but it doesn't with Vue.

Comment: can you create jsfiddle/snippet to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I just figured out now: i had to use `@keyup="fetchData($event)"`: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Comment: I just figured it too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the vue js example, missing `@keyup="fetchData($event)"`  passing event into debounce

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      keywords: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData: _.debounce(function(e) {
      console.log(e.keyCode) // return undefined
    }, 500)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input id="textInput" @keyup="fetchData($event)" />
</div>
```

Comment: Right, issue happened because i've used `()` rounded brackets, it counted as inline handler with empty parameters, so even an `event` object didn't passed in. You have 2 choices: 1 - remove brackets, 2 - add `$event` parameter if you plan to use inline handlers.

Comment: @AlexanderKim exactly!